# Magento 2 failed to open stream: No such file or directory 'vendor/magento/framework/registration.php'

Tags: php, magento, installation, registration, magento2

I am not sure what's going on with my magento installation.

I downloaded the latest version of Magento 2.1.1 as zip.
Extracted, setup a database then tried running the install but I keep on getting this stup*d error and I could not find any answers online.

[image]

Can someone help me on this one please? Its been a while since I used magento since I got used to working with Wordpress websites.

I tried looking for the file manually, but just like the error said, it does not exist. Where can I find this registration.php file under magento/framework/ folder?

Comment: Something gone wrong with installation, or your installation files were corrupted. Try again downloading and installing

Comment: Perhaps it might be windows backslashes \ vs forward slashes / in your path names?

Answer (score 12):

Try run this command in your magento root folder.

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Then reload page you've got this error.

Still not working ?. Fell free to reply :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using composer to Install, the solution is simple re run the commands from the Magento Root Folder.

Inside /vendor/autoload.php there is a Base Path Global Variable that take the path to execute the vendor_path.php, and, in my case, it take the path where I am and not the Root.

I hope this is helpful for someone. 
Have a nice coding day

Answer (score 0):

please run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to reload composer autoload files this issue mostly when you update a library and then fall back to original but magento composer files doesn't fall back to original so you need to generate files again.